# Clean Urls without HTACCESS on WebDav server

Tags: 7, uri

I am not able to have a .htaccess on my webdav server. Am I completely out of luck to use clean urls on my Drupal 7 install? If not, how do I go about this? I've read a ton of posts, but they all relate to .htaccess enabled.